# How do we access related object fields using custom setting on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've got one head scratcher of a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I have one Contact object which has lookup relationship on account. I have created Custom setting and added releted fields(Account) in it. At the time of accessing the Custom setting on VF page, i am getting an error.

> Unknown property '$ObjectType.Contact.fields.Account' Error is in
>   expression
>   '{!$ObjectType.Contact.fields[contactField].Label}{!IF(contactSortField
>   =='#{contactField}',IF(contactSortOrder='asc','?','?'),'')}' in component  in page globalsearch Error evaluating
>   dynamic reference 'Account'

thnx in advanced

Comment: try AccountId hope it will work

Comment: thnx for reply !!!
bt nope it is not working i already tried  AccounId...:(
and it is showing error :::::duplicate field selected: AccountId
Error is in expression '{!performSearch}' in page globalsearch: Class.GlobalContactSearch.getContactDataSet: line 530, column 1
Class.GlobalContactSearch.performSearch: line 196, column 1

Comment: Are you trying to access field labels for things like Account.Name, Account.Phone, etc but using $ObjectType.Contact? I don't think that is going to work. You'll need to use $ObjectType.Account

Answer (score 1):

1) you need to use AccountId in that merge expression
2) if you are then getting a `duplicate field selected` error, you need to examine the code being called. I assume that your `getContactDataSet` method is building a dynamic query, so you should probably hold all the potential query fields in a `Set<String>` before building the query string from them. Perhaps I can offer more direct help if you post the apex code.